# How to apply tablesorter correctly?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have been all over the place since yesterday to find a soloution for my problem.
I have a table where i sort some of my colums and some i dont. One of these is a textboxinput where i use a parser. My problem then?
Well the colums in the textboxes get sorted the first time i click on that row BUT they get sorrtet in the wrong order and then the second time i click on it to sort again it does not do anything.

I think this is weird and have started to check my other jquery files to see if i have anything that might be preventing this but I wanted to check if my code is correct and what better placce to do so then here.

I have been reading up on tablesorter from these links:

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

my code:

```
 // custom sorting of value in text input   
 $.tablesorter.addParser({
     id: 'input_text',
     is: function (s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected  
            return false;
         },
         format: function (s) {
            return $(s).attr('value');
         },
         type: 'text'
     });
     // Tablesorter
      if ($(".attendanceList tbody tr").length > 0) {
           $(".attendanceList").tablesorter({ headers: { 
                 1: { sorter: false },
                 2: { sorter: 'input_text' },
                 3: { sorter: false },
                 4: { sorter: false },
                 5: { sorter: false },
                 6: { sorter: false },
                 7: { sorter: false },
                 8: { sorter: false },
                 9: { sorter: false },
                 10: { sorter: false}
           },
           sortList: [[2, 1], [0, 0]]
           });
 }
```

picture of my problem:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/sorterprob.jpg/]

EDIT:

I forgott to mention that the sort shall also be able to sort on letters not only numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this some time ago but forgott to update. 
The problem was that this code

```
return $(s).attr('value')
```

gave me an undefined value so
i changed it to:

```
return s
```

and the sorting worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".attendanceList").tablesorter({
     headers: {
        column Number: { sorter: 'digit' } 
     }
 });
```

Comment: <th class= "\{sorter: 'digit'}\">Grupp</th>

I assume u ment to do it like this. since the way you typed it gave me errors, in any case it did not work:(. thanks for the tip!

Comment: This did the trick, only one problem. I totaly forgot to mention that even though the example only shows numbers, it can also contain leatters. Which means that the sorting shall be able to sort numbers AND letters

Answer (score 0):

change `type: 'text'` to `type: 'numeric'`